# Why does DateTime::createFromFormat() method turn out to be undefined?

Tags: php

Here's the PHP code.

```
public function storeUser($name, $email, $password, $str_birthday) {
    $uuid = uniqid('', true);
    $hash = $this->hashSSHA($password);
    $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted_password"]; // encrypted password
    $salt = $hash["salt"]; // salt
    $dob = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $str_birthday)->format('Y-m-d');

    $result = mysqli_query($this->db->connect(), "INSERT INTO users(unique_id, name, email, encrypted_password, birthday, salt, created_at) VALUES('$uuid', '$name', '$email', '$encrypted_password', '$dob', '$salt', NOW())");

    // check for successful store
    if ($result) {

        // get user details
        $result = mysqli_query($this->db->connect(), "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'");

        // return user details
        return mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

After running the command on the browser, it says the following part is undefined.

`$dob = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $str_birthday)->format('Y-m-d');`

But I already have found quite many suggestions to use that method to change the date format to store it into MySQL database.

Comment: Are you sure the `$str_birthday` is always provided? Note the documentation saying that `Returns a new DateTime instance or FALSE on failure` (and thus you cannot call `->format('Y-m-d')` in these cases).

Comment: There was also a good comment here on PHP version but disappeared. Note that `DateTime::createFromFormat` is available for PHP >= 5.3.0.

Comment: @jso `DateTime::createFromFormat` is available, but the thing is next; `->format()` function seems to be undefined.

Comment: @jso Like, for example, When I start typing `DateTime::createFromFormat` in Eclipse, it is suggested, but `->format()` is not available, saying 'No Default proposals'.

Comment: Is is only an issue in Eclipse or when you run the code? Note that `->format()` is not always available though because it depends on the input: `DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', '01/01/2015')` will return `DateTime` but `DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', '01/01/xy')` will return `false` so obviously you cannot use `->format()` then.

Comment: _"it says the following part is undefined"_ What does it **actually** say? Exactly? Precisely?

Comment: What version of PHP?

Answer (score -2):

Much easier way to accomplish this:

```
$dob = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($str_birthday));
```

Comment: Recommending _older_ and less versatile solutions without explanation is not a good idea. Besides, you didn't answer the question.